# quotes around int values in mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

I've gotten a habit of filtering the user submitted variable through my int function which makes sure it's a number (if not returns 0) and not quoting the variable in mysql queries.

Is that bad practice? I think I decided to do this for performance reasons. Plus I've always thought that numbers shouldn't be put in quotes.

Example:

```
if($perpage != $user['perpage']){
if($perpage == 50 || $perpage == 100 || $perpage == 200 ){
$DB->query("UPDATE users SET perpage=$perpage WHERE id=$user[id]", __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
}
```

Comment: I am interested in knowing if I gain anything in terms of performance by doing this. Obviously I'd feel much safer putting them in quotes.

Comment: it seems you are using some ancient way of getting file and line of the error. There is no need to set it manually nowadays. trigger_error() or debug_backtrace() will do it for you

Comment: as for the performance. Do you experience any issues with it right now?

Comment: @Col The site isn't up yet... I'm recoding an older script. It used to utilize 100% of mysql's memory (server had 4GB of ram) with 200 people online at once. I'll look into the functions you named. Sounds like I've done a lot of redundant work.

Comment: Well, if you have a legacy code with performance issues, a wise choice would be not to fight some irrelevant issues at random but **to profile** your application and find the real cause(s).

Comment: I agree with Matt, you can simply typecast the variable as an int before passing to the query. `$myVar = (int) $myVar`. But I do the same as you Domino, never wrap quotes around numeric values when working with MySQL via command-line, so no reason to do it in the app layer either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aha! an interesting case here!

1. You are right in general. It is always better to treat numbers as numbers, not strings

   - it makes your code more sane and consistent
   - an `strict_mode` setting in mysql, which won't allow you do disguise a number as a string, if turned on.
2. But your implementation in fact allows an injection! Let's leave it for your homework to find it :)

Here is a reference for you, explaining this injection: http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling

so, I'd make your code like this

```
$perpage = intval($perpage);
if($perpage != $user['perpage'] && in_array($perpage,array(50,100,200) { 
  $DB->query("UPDATE users SET perpage=$perpage WHERE id=$user[id]"); 
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the second "if". The value can only be 50, 100 or 200. No room for injections. ;)

Comment: I don't get it. If anything but those three numbers were to pass to the query, then it would be vulnerable. $perpage cannot be anything else but a number anyway.

Comment: it seems you arent familiar with PHP yet :) as simple $perpage as `"50 inject anything here"` will pass your verification. You have to **cast** your numbers, not just compare.

Comment: Omg, I don't understand why or how, but you seem to be right. Which also means I have a site full of security holes. This is not a good day at all. So by casting you mean I have to put quotes around them and use them as strings? Completely illogical.

Comment: no. by casting I mean explicit casting to desired type. as Matt suggested, use `intval()` for the integers and it would be pretty safe.

Comment: I already do that, so I guess it's fine. But I still fail to understand how a number with a space + text can pass that. Is that even legal? lol

Comment: I added a link to my answer. You may start from it and then go a little deeper. All that matter exmplained well there. In two words it is called "loose typing".

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way about the file and line, if I get rid of the current system, do I have to use the functions you named after every query just like I kind of do now?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the values are properly checked through the use of PHP's intval method before using them, I don't see an issue with it. You could do yourself some favors in the future by doing that if you ever have to interact with a DB that thinks quotes around int values are a syntax error. (I believe MS SQL server does that.)